# Java XmlRPC Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, xml-rpc

Any clue or example on how to implement basic authentication for XMLRPC using 
org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.WebServer?

I'm using the Java API  apache-xmlrpc-3.1.2 and I'm not being able to implement authentication without org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.ServletWebServer

Answer (score 4):

There is an example in Apache XML-RPC [documentation](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/server.html). Look in BasicAuthentication section.